# How to create a dropdown list of country codes for phone authentication?

Tags: android, firebase

If I want to authenticate my users via a phone number, what is the best way to add a drop down of all countries with their country code, so that they won't have to manually write "+xxx"?

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be easily handled using a third-party library. Add [`Country Code Picker (CCP)`](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject) library to your project and let it handle the country code things for you. For this what you have to do :

1. Add this to your Gradle file and sync

   ```
   dependencies {
     implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.3'
   }
   ```

   ***NOTE*** : Check [original documentation](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject) for any updates of this library.
2. Add CCP view to XML layout

   ```
   <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
       android:id="@+id/ccp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   ```
3. Add CCP object in Activity / Fragment

   ```
   CountryCodePicker ccp;
   ```
4. Bind CCP from the layout

   ```
   ccp = findViewById(R.id.ccp);
   ```
5. That's it. Run the project and see the results.
6. To blend CCP with your project's theme style, you can modify [CCP Theme](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/CCP-Theme-Customization) and [CCP Dialog Theme](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki/CCP-Dialog-Theme-Customization).

For customization check out their [wiki](https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/wiki) page.

Comment: How safe is it to use 3rd party code? I'm a beginner, wonder if using 3rd party code can somehow "steal" data etc?

Comment: No, it's not like that. Your data is safe. You are just using their code to implement your idea.

Comment: Please be sure to accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Please note that 3rd-party libraries are NOT necessarily safe; they could literally contain anything. However, a library that's wracked up hundreds of stars and contributors on GitHub is generally safe, as malicious code would presumably have been rooted out by others (emphasis on presumably). Best way is to take a look for yourself! Hope that helps to clarify things a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Do an `spinner` and populate it with the list of country codes

Here's a link to an api that retrieves the list for you https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: You should have posted this as comment.